# Bind jQuery Mobile swipe event to a DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, mobile, bind

I ran into a small problem and I'm sure that somebody from the stackoverflow community might have the answer.

I'm trying to build a custom swipe event and bind it to a div with id="swipe". I use jQuery Mobile 1.1.1. I Googled around for a couple of hours this morning but unsuccessfully ...

**My code**

```
<script>
  $('#swipe').bind('swipe', function () {
     alert('Hello!');
  });
<script>    

<div id="swipe">Swipe here</div>
```

I've tried using .live() instead of .bind() but still no good. The weird thing is that if I use

```
<script>
  $(document).bind('swipe', function () {
     alert('Hello!');
  });
<script>
```

... it's working perfectly but on the whole page of course instead of just the #swipe DIV.

Any ideas are highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess $('#swipe') will not return the element since you are executing this code before the element is defined. move the script to the bottom or use the onload event.

Comment: I tried to move it after the div and in the footer as well ... Still not working. I'm not sure about the onload event, can you provide a code snippet I could try, please?

Comment: $(function() {
 $('#swipe').bind('swipe', function () {
  alert('Hello!');
 });
});

Comment: btw. what does alert($('#swipe').length); return when you insert this line after the bind function?

Comment: using   $("#swipe").bind('swipe', function (event) { alert('Hello!'); }); alert($('#swipe').length);   returns "0"

Comment: so the element could not be found. please could you upload the whole html file to pastebin.com and give me the link to the file?

Comment: Hmm, I just moved your code to the function that gets called on load and the element could be found without any problems. see the following link http://pastebin.com/g3eithXu

Comment: Indeed, have to agree ... I just tested it like this http://pastebin.com/d18hMepL and it returns "1" ... so far so good but once I test it on my iPhone still wont swipe ... (on iPhone the "1" value is also returned) ...

Comment: Then it should work actually ... could you increase the swipe region? maybe it's too small.

Comment: Just tried with an extended area of 500x200px ... same ... I'll throw my iPhone out the window just 1 sec :)

Comment: does any other event trigger on this element? so if you bind the click event .. will it show the alert message on click?

Comment: btw. try this $(document).on('swipe', '#swipe', function(event) { alert('hello'); });

Comment: Pascal you made it! :) Thanks a mill! $(document).on('swipe', '#swipe', function(event) { alert('hello'); }); worked like a charm! Excellent idea! I own you a couple of beers ... Really, thanks a lot mate!

Comment: Great! I'm happy to hear that! Cheeeers!

Answer (score 0):

Try it with the script tag *after* the div.

Comment: Also either change div to have id "swipe" or change your jQuery selector to use ".swipe" instead of "#swipe".

Comment: Yes, sorry that was my mistake ... A typo ... I'm using id instead of class ... Will edit the post. Thanks for letting me know!